# an $\mathbb F$- representation of the matroid $M_1 \oplus M_2.$

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, combinatorial-geometry, algebraic-combinatorics

Suppose that $A_1$ and $A_1$ are $\mathbb F$- representations of the matroids $M_1$ and $M_2$ respectively, show that
$$\begin{matrix}
A_1& 0\\
0 & A_2
\end{matrix}$$

is an $\mathbb F$- representation of the matroid $M_1 \oplus M_2.$

**My idea is:**

Construction a function that is not exactly the identity but the identity plus zero for each of the columns of the last matrix of $M_1 \oplus M_2.$ But I am confused of how to write this rigorously. Could someone help me in this please?

Comment: its not $\otimes$ is $\oplus$. Just check the basis. What is your definition of direct sum?\

Comment: thanks! I will edit my post ..... Which basis? Could you please provide more details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The independent sets of the direct sum are unions of independents from each of the original matroids (notice that the ground sets are disjoint, call them $X_1$ and $X_2$). Call $\mathcal{A}$ the matrix that you propose as the representation and consider $A\subseteq X_1\cup X_2$. The claim is that $$A\in \mathbb{I}_{M_1\oplus M_2} \text{ iff  }c_A = \{c_x:x\in A\} \text{ are L.I},$$
where $c_x$ is a column indexed by $x$ in the matrix $\mathcal{A}$. 
 Let $A\in \mathbb{I}_{M_1\oplus M_2}$, then $A = A_1\cup A_2$ with $A_1\in \mathbb{I}_{M_1}$ and $A_2\in \mathbb{I}_{M_2}$, then  $c_{A_1}=\{c_x:x\in A_1\}$ and $c_{A_1}=\{c_x:x\in A_2\}$ are independent. Now, to see that $c_{A}$ is L.I, suppose the opposite, then there are scalars $s_x$ not all zero such that $\sum _{x\in A}s_x\cdot c_x=0$, but clearly $\sum _{x\in A}s_x\cdot c_x=\sum _{x\in A_1}s_x\cdot c_x+\sum _{x\in A_2}s_x\cdot c_x$. Now, by construction of the matrix $\mathcal{A}$ one can see that $\sum _{x\in A_1}s_x\cdot c_x = (b_1,b_2,\cdots ,b_n,0,0,\cdots ,0)^T$ and $\sum _{x\in A_2}s_x\cdot c_x = (0,0,\cdots ,0,b'_1,b'_2,\cdots ,b'_m)^T$ with $n = |X_1|,m = |X_2|$, and so the only way they add up to the zero vector is if both of them are zero, but this is a contradiction in the independence of $A_1$ and $A_2$.
The other direction is immediate **why?**

Comment: I will read it thoroughly and let you know "why", thanks!

Comment: @Secretly Great, let me know!